# Dev C++ Access Violation (Segmentation Fault) error

Tags: c++

i was executing this code, when i encountered an error.
By executing the Debugger the error was so "An Access Violation (Segmentation Fault) error raised in you program".

```
/* Statcstr.cpp
* Le stringhe sono in realta' array static
*/
#pragma hdrstop
#include <condefs.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream.h>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma argsused
int Modifica();
void Attesa(char *);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
while( Modifica() );
Attesa("terminare");
return 0;
}
int Modifica() {
static unsigned int i = 0; // Per contare all'interno della stringa
char *st = "Stringa di tipo static\n";
if(i < strlen(st)) { // Conta i caratteri nella stringa
cout << st; // Stampa la stringa
st[i] = 'X'; //<--- THIS IS THE FAILING INSTRUCTION
i++; // Punta al prossimo carattere
return 1;
} else
return 0; // Indica che la stringa e' finita
}
void Attesa(char * str) {
cout << "\n\n\tPremere return per " << str;
cin.get();
}
```

Could you please tell me how can i solve?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

```
char *st = "Stringa di tipo static\n";
           //this resides in read-only memory
```

Try declaring it as

```
char st[] = "Stringa di tipo static\n";
            //this is a string you own
```

Or, since this is C++, you should use `std::string`.

Comment: In this way the string is treated as characters array, isn't it? Thank you for the information about strings, i didn't know (i'm new in programming)... is there a reason?          Anyway in this way it works fine!